# recipe for target 'o.le-v7-g/.moc/moc_applicationui.cpp' failed

Tags: c++, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, momentics

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE (native SDK).

For a reason that I don't know, momentics show always the following debug error even when I create a new cascade project :

***"recipe for target 'o.le-v7-g/.moc/moc_applicationui.cpp' failed"***

I tried everything; re-install momentics, clean registry, try to changing the debug config., changing working space for projects, clean and rebuilt the project, reboot my computer. But nothing, the error still there, I'm losing my mind with this.

What should I do ? Can anyone help me on this ? I will be very grateful ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case I forgot to include a library that I was using in the .pro. For example if you are using system dialog, you have to link against this class, add the following line to your .pro file: LIBS += -lbbsystem
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__systemdialog.html